# How to re-create Underscore.js _.reduce method?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, reduce

For education purposes, I was trying to re-create Underscore.js's `_.reduce()` method. While I was able to do this in an explicit style using for loops. But this is far from ideal because it mutates the original list that was supplied as an argument, which is dangerous.

I also realized that creating such method using functional programming style is harder, since it is not possible to explicitly set `i` value for looping.

```
// Explicit style
var reduce = function(list, iteratee, initial) {
if (Array.isArray(list)) {
    var start;
    if (arguments.length === 3) {
        start = initial;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            start = iteratee(start, list[i], i);
        }
    } else {
        start = list[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            start = iteratee(start, list[i], i);
        }
    }
}
if (list.constructor === Object) {
    var start;
    if (arguments.length === 3) {
        start = initial;
        for (var key in list) {
            start = iteratee(start, list[key], key);
        }
    } else {
        start = list[Object.keys(list)[0]];

        // Delete the first property to avoid duplication.
        delete list[Object.keys(list)[0]];
        for (var key in list) {
            start = iteratee(start, list[key], key);
        }
    }
}

return start;
};
```

What makes me struggle is that when my `reduce()` is supplied with an argument, `initial`, I need to subsequently either skip or remove the first `element` or `property` of the argument, `list` for the final value that will be returned. Because not doing so will double count the first element/property. I can't think of how I could do such thing when creating the function with functional programming style, with `_.each()` or `forEach()` involved.

This is my functional style of `reduce()` that is working partially. It works correctly when `memo`(initial value) is supplied, because I don't need to skip the first element/property. But it's not working correctly when memo is not supplied, because then I'm setting memo to either first element or property, and I should be able to skip it during the looping, which I don't know how.

```
// Functional style (not working without memo)
var reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo) {
    var memo = memo || list[0] || list[Object.keys(list)[0]];
    _.each(list, function(element, index, list){
        memo = iteratee(memo, element, index, list);
    });
    return memo;
};
```

I spent quite a long time searching for answers to my question on Google. But wasn't able to find one. I would really appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Lastly, this is an additional code I came up with which does not work, but I think it should.

```
var reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo) {
    var collection = list;
    var accumulation;

    _.each(collection, function(item){
        if (arguments.length < 3) {
            if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
                accumulation = collection[0];
                collection.shift();
                accumulation = iteratee(accumulation, item);
            } else {
                accumulation = collection[Object.keys(collection)[0]];
                delete collection[Object.keys(collection)[0]];
                accumulation = iteratee(accumulation, item);
            }
        } else {
            accumulation = memo;
            accumulation = iteratee(accumulation, item);
        }
    });

    return accumulation;
};
```

Comment: You may not be aware that plain old JavaScript [already comes with reduce() for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so why not start by making use of that instead of rolling lots of `for` loops?

Comment: Well if the OP needs to support IE 8, then they would not have access to `Array.prototype.reduce()`.  Additionally, the OP mentioned this was an academic exercise.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your opinion. I'm aware of the native Array method `reduce()`. I was not making use of it because I wanted to learn how it was composed, plus I wanted to make it support an Object as its list argument too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the shortest version I could come up with.

```
_.reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo){
  var memoUndefined = arguments.length < 3;
  _.each(list, function(elem, index, list){
    if(memoUndefined) {
      memoUndefined = false;
      memo = elem;
    } else memo = iteratee(memo, elem, index, list);
  });
  return memo;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It works on both Array & Object as a list and with/without `memo` also. I guess `elem` keeps its index order even for the case where the list is Ojbect? Is this correct?

Comment: Seems like without using `_.each()` it will become much more complicated to implement `reduce()` that supports both on Array and Object as its list.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce accepts three parameters: A collection (array or object), callback, and accumulator (this one is optional).

Reduce iterates through the collection, which invokes the callback and keeps track of the result in the accumulator.

If an accumulator is not passed in, we'll set it to the first element of the collection.

If an accumulator is available, we'll set the accumulator to be equal to the result of invoking the callback and passing in the current accumulator and the current element of the collection. Remember: Javascript executes its operations in right-to-left order, meaning the right side of the operator occurs first before it gets assigned to the variable on the left.

```
  _.reduce = function(collection, callback, accumulator){
    _.each(collection, function(elem){
      return accumulator === undefined ? accumulator = collection[0] : accumulator = callback(accumulator, elem);
    });

    return accumulator;
  };
```

Comment: So if `callback` returns `undefined` somewhere, you'd pass the first element again in the next iteration?

Comment: I see how you are returning a ternary operator with a recursive call to callback. Does that mean it keeps accumulating the result from `_.each()` to arguments object's `accumulator` until all iterations are complete for the list? Also, I checked your code and it seems to work for 1) Array as a list with memo, 2) Array as a list without memo, 3) Object as a list with memo, but does not work for Object as a list without memo. It returns `undefined`.

I saved your function to `var reduce`.
`reduce({"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}, function(a, b){ return a + b; });
// returns undefined`

Comment: Can you atually access your collection by `collection[0]` even if your collection is an object?

Comment: Ok it's working when I changed `accumulator = collection[0]` in the return statement to `accumulator = elem`.

Comment: @RichardKho I tried playing with some test cases and I noticed that if you don't include `return` in the third line of your snippet, it still works exactly the same. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a way to determine whether `reduce` received an initial `memo` value when you are inside the function you pass to `_.each`. You could do this a number of ways. One way is to simply set a flag based on the length of `arguments`. You need to do this outside the `_.each` call because the function you pass to `_.each` will have its own `arguments` object, masking the `arguments` object for `reduce`.

Using your code as a starting point:

```
var reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo) {
    var considerFirst = arguments.length > 2;
    var memo = memo || list[0] || list[Object.keys(list)[0]];
    _.each(list, function(element, index, list){
        if (index > 0 || considerFirst) {
            memo = iteratee(memo, element, index, list);
        }
    });
    return memo;
};
```

This still isn't quite right, though. We also need to update how you are defaulting `memo`. Currently, if `memo` receives a falsy value (e.g. `0`), we still set it to the fist element in the list, but we don't set the flag indicating to ignore the first element. This means `reduce` will process the first element twice.

To get this right, you need to change how you are defaulting `memo`, setting it only if no argument is passed in. You could do something like this:

```
var reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo) {
    var considerFirst = true;
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        memo = list[0];
        considerFirst = false;
    } 
    _.each(list, function(element, index, list){
        if (index > 0 || considerFirst) {
            memo = iteratee(memo, element, index, list);
        }
    });
    return memo;
};
```

This way, you only set `memo` if no argument was passed.

Note that you don't need to initialize `memo` with `var`. Having `memo` as a parameter does all the initialization you need.

Also note that I removed support for using `reduce` on a plain object. When you pass an object to `_.each`, the value of the `index` parameter is not a numerical index but the key for that entry, which may or may not be an integer. This does not play well with our `index > 0` check to see if we are looking at the first entry. There are ways around this, but it doesn't seem central to your question. Check out the actual [underscore implementation](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) if you want to see how to make it work.

Update: the implementation SpiderPig suggests doesn't rely on `index` and so would work with objects, not just arrays.

Lastly, it's worth pointing out that [underscore's implementation](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) of `_.reduce` uses a `for` loop and not `_.each`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. I really appreciate it. I now understand how I should have put my check for `memo` outside `_.each()`. Thank you. But when I tried your code, it did not work on Object as a list without memo being supplied. I guess it's because you're assigning memo with `list[0]`. It seems SpiderPig's set it as `memo = elem` and it's working. But really if I didn't want to depend on `_.each` would it become much more difficult to support my `reduce()` for both Array and Object as lists?