# Recreating JavaScript Reduce function part 2

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js, reduce

This in relation to the reduce function I recreated here, but a different question: [Recreating JavaScript's reduce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527561/recreating-javascripts-reduce-function/34527827#34527827).

I am reading Eloquent JavaScript and noticed that they recreated the reduce function a slightly different way with less code:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0)); // → 10
```

I noticed that this only works when there is a start. For example, if I took away the start(0) and it was just:

```
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
})); // NaN
```

It would return NaN. This doesn't make sense to me because the book says:
"If your array contains at least one element, you are allowed to leave off the start argument. The method will take the first element of the array as its start value and start reducing at the second element."

Only when I adjust it with an if statement does it produce "10" with or without a start(0).

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(current !==undefined){
      current = combine(current, array[i]);
    }else{
      current=array[i]; 
    }

 return current;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Evidently the book is wrong. Have you tried checking the [errata](http://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/errata.html)?

Comment: it should be `var current = typeof start === 'undefined' ? array[0] : start;`

Comment: @Louy not quite, because then you add the zeroth element twice.

Comment: yeah you are right, he should change the loop start index too

Comment: I think this is how it should work. [Check the actual implementation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @raminbakhshpour is it necessary to change the start index? I was thinking about that too but the program would instinctively go to the first if there is no start since index starts at 0, otherwise if no start then it would be the number at 0. So I just left it as array[i] not array[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it should be, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (simplified version here):

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  var i = 0;
  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    while (array[i] === undefined) {
      i ++;
      if (array.length >= i) {
        throw new Error('Empty array with no initial value');
      }
    }
    current = array[i];
  }

  for (; i < array.length; ++ i) {
    if (array[i] === undefined) continue;
    if (current !== undefined) {
      current = combine(current, array[i]);
    } else {
      current=array[i]; 
    }
  }

  return current;
}
```

Comment: Just fixed an infinite loop. You need that error to be thrown. I believe the version in the book is too simplified it doesn't work in many cases. You're welcome 